# Why spark streaming executors start at different time?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, timeline

I'm using Spark streaming 1.6 which uses kafka as a source

My input arguments are as follows:

```
num-executors    5
num-cores        4
batch Interval  10 sec
maxRate         600
blockInterval   350 ms
```

Why does some of my executors start later than another ??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not executors' start time, but tasks' start time.

This is most likely due to locality scheduling. Spark delayed the start of a task to find the best executor to run that task on. Check the configuration "spark.locality.wait" in [Spark's documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#scheduling) for further details.